# Running cucumber-groovy features against a spring boot api

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot, cucumber, spring-annotations

I've been attempting to get cucumber-groovy working with spring-boot, but it's not been going well. I get the error `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/applicants": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` which seems to indicate that it's hitting the endpoint, but that the service isn't running.

I've read that I need to have a `cucumber.xml` file, but my project is not using any xml config, it's all annotations, so instead I've got this:

```
package support
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.base.package")
public class CucumberConfiguration {}
```

I've added it to the `World`, but this seems to be the wrong way of doing things (i.e. I don't know how to add an annotation on groovy step defs).

```
package support

import com.thing.app.Application
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader
import org.springframework.boot.test.WebIntegrationTest
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration  
import static cucumber.api.groovy.Hooks.*

//@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner)
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader)
//@WebAppConfiguration
//@WebIntegrationTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CucumberConfiguration)
public class AbstractTest {

}

World() {
    new AbstractTest()
}

Before() {}

After() {}
```

I left in my other annotations to kind of show what I've done so far. None of it has worked.

I've also tried setting up an AbstractDefs class as seen here https://github.com/jakehschwartz/spring-boot-cucumber-example/tree/master/src/test/java/demo, but that also hasn't worked, mostly because I'm not using the cucumber-java style of things, but instead the cucumber-groovy style, which doesn't use step definition classes.

Edit: Just discovered I was doing things wrong by having an `env.groovy`, I'm used to the ruby cucumber, so I'm having trouble finding all the little problems. Still am having the same issue though, I don't know how to execute in a Spring context.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate Spring test context with `io.cucumber.spring.SpringFactory` and register adapter in `World` to allow groovy script has access to Spring beans:

env.groovy:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration, loader = SpringBootContextLoader)
class CucumberContextConfiguration {
}

//adapter bypassing World properties to Spring context    
class SpringFactoryWorldAdapter {
    private final SpringFactory factory;

    SpringFactoryWorldAdapter(SpringFactory factory)  {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    Object getProperty(String s) {
        return factory.testContextManager.getContext().getBean(s);
    }
}

def factory; //Keep state to prevent repeated context initialization
World { args ->
   if (factory == null) {
       factory = new SpringFactory()
       factory.addClass(CucumberContextConfiguration)
       factory.start()
   }
   new SpringFactoryWorldAdapter(factory)
}
```